# How do I "read" a variable on a while loop

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop

How can I read from variable with `while read line`?

For example:

```
the_list=$(..code..)

while read line
do
        echo $line

done < $the_list
```

using the code above gives me error:

```
./copy.sh: line 25: $the_list: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can write:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done <<< "$the_list"
```

See [§3.6.7 "Here Strings" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

(I've also taken the liberty of adding some double-quotes, and adding `-r` and `IFS=` to `read`, to avoid too much mucking around with the contents of your variables.)

Comment: Does `IFS=` set the IFS to null character? Why do you need it in this case?

Comment: @doubleDown: `IFS=` sets `$IFS` to the empty string (so it doesn't contain any characters at all). In this case, since there's only one field, its only effect is to prevent the removal of leading IFS-characters from the start of the line. (To see what I mean, compare `read foo <<< ' bar' ; echo "$foo"` with `IFS= read foo <<< ' bar' ; echo "$foo"`.)

Answer (score 31):

If you do not use the variable for anything else, you can even do without it:

```
while read line ; do
    echo $line
done < <( ... code ... )
```

Answer (score 27):

You can just use

```
your_code | while read line;
do
    echo $line
done
```

if you don't mind the while loop executing in a subshell (any variables you modify won't be visible in the parent after the `done`).

Comment: This is an old reply. I am interested in the "...(any variables you modify won't be visible in the parent after the done)." part of the statement. How will they be then _visible_? The following example `echo "${NAMES/,/$'\n'}" |while read -r NAME ;do TMP=${NAME#*_} ;TMP2=${TMP%_*_*_*_*_*} ;OUTPUT+=${TMP2/$'\n'/,} ;done` won't return anything with `echo $OUTPUT` after the loop, for example.

Comment: They won't, as I said. You're creating and/or modifying variables in a different process. However, variables are not the only form of output: the loop can still print output directly to the shared stdout (as, in fact, this example does), and it can still operate on files which persist after the subshell exits.

Comment: Thanks (again)! The following somewhat elaborated example works exactly the way I need :-): Looping over `NAMES=x_myd11a1_lst_night_2019_01_01T01_30_00,x_myd21a1_lst_night_2019_01_01T01_30_00` via `while read -r NAME; do TMP=${NAME#*_}  ;TMP2="${TMP%_*_*_*_*_*}" ;if [ -z $OUTPUT ] ;then OUTPUT+=${TMP2:-$TMP2} ;else OUTPUT+=${OUTPUT:+,$TMP2} ;fi ;done <<< ${NAMES//,/$'\n'*}` derives the `OUTPUT` variable  `echo $OUTPUT`: `myd11a1_lst_night,myd21a1_lst_night`.

Answer (score -5):

Script file should be in Linux mode. Previously it was in dos mode. I changed it by using  `dos2unix filename`.

e.g.:

```
dos2unix sshcopy.sh
```

Now it works for me.

Comment: The answer proposed by [ruakh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13122491/622391) was accepted by the asker. This means that the problem was _not_ related to the script's file format.