# Bash: Keeping indentation during interpolation

Tags: bash

I have a variable containing a multiline string.

I am going to interpolate this variable into another multiline echoed string, this echoed string has indentation.

Here's an example:

```
ip_status=`ip -o addr | awk 'BEGIN {  printf "%-12s %-12s %-12s\n", "INTERFACE", "PROTOCOL", "ADDRESS"
                                      printf "%-12s %-12s %-12s\n", "---------", "--------", "-------" }
                                   {  printf "%-12s %-12s %-12s\n", $2, $3, $4 }'`

echo -e "
    ->
    $ip_status
    ->
"
```

When running that, the first line of $ip_status is left justified against the `->`, however the subsequent lines are not justified against the `->`.

It's easier to see if you run that in your bash. This is the output:

```
    ->
    INTERFACE    PROTOCOL     ADDRESS
---------    --------     -------
lo           inet         127.0.0.1/8
lo           inet6        ::1/128
eth0         inet         10.0.2.15/24
eth0         inet6        fe80::a00:27ff:fed3:76c/64
    ->
```

I want all the lines in the `$ip_status` to be aligned with the `->`, not just the first line.

Comment: Well you can add spaces with `sed` for exmaple: `echo "$ip_status" | sed 's/^/            /'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo  "    ->"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "    $line"
done <<< "$ip_status"
echo  "    ->"
```

You can read the variable line by line and echo it with the number of spaces you need before it. I have used the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13122441/3495601).

---

To make it a function:

```
myfunction() {
echo  "    ->"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "    $line"
done <<< "$1"
echo  "    ->"
}

myfunction "$ip_status"
```

Comment: Such a construct should be wrapped in a function no?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, you can do it, specially if you need it more than once, I've edited my answer to include a function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to insert the indentation yourself. Bash comes with no feature for making text pretty, although there are some possibly useful utilities (`column -t` is frequently useful in this sort of application, for example).

Still, inserting indentation isn't too difficult. Here's one solution:

```
echo "
    ->
    ${ip_status//$'\n'/$'\n    '}
    ->
"
```

Note: I removed the non-standard `-e` flag because it really isn't necessary.

Another alternative would be to apply the replacement on the entire output, using a tool like `sed`:

```
echo "
 ->
   $ip_status
   ->
" | sed 's/^ */    /'
```

This second one has the possible advantage that it will tidy up the indentation, even if it were ragged as in the example. If you didn't want that effect, use `'s/^/    /'` instead.

Or a little shell function whose first argument is the desired indent and whose remaining arguments are indented and concatenated with a newline after each one:

```
indent() {
  local s=$(printf '%*s' $1 "")
  shift
  printf "$s%s\n" "${@//$'\n'/$'\n'$s}"
}
indent 4 '->' "$ip_status" '->'
```

That might require some explanation:

- `printf` accepts `*` as a length specifier, just like the C version. It means "use the corresponding argument as the numeric value". So `local s=$(printf '%*s' $1 "")` creates a string of spaces of length `$1`.
- Also, `printf` repeats its format as often as necessary to consume all arguments. So the second `printf` applies an indent at the beginning and a newline at the end to each argument.
- `"${@/pattern/subst}"` is a substitution applied to each argument in turn. Using two slashes at the beginning (`"${@//pattern/subst}"`) makes it a repeated substitution.
- `$'\n'` is a common syntax for interpreting C-style backslash escapes, implemented by bash and a variety of other shells. (But it's not available in a minimal posix standard shell.)
- So `"${@//$'\n'/$'\n'$s}"` inserts `$s` -- that is, the desired indentation -- after every newline in each argument.

Comment: Your first example doesn't seem to work. It doesn't keep the indentation.

Comment: Why does the @ need to `//` after it? Why does it need 2 forward slashes and what is the shift for?

Comment: Oh shift is for essentially ignoring the first number.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Sorry, there was a small typo in the first example (I wrote `'$\n'` instead of the correct `$'\n'`). It's fixed now. The answer includes an explanation of `${@//`. You'll find more details in the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

A simple form is to use `readarray`, process substitution and `printf`:

```
readarray -t ip_status < <(exec ip -o addr | awk 'BEGIN {  printf "%-12s %-12s %-12s\n", "INTERFACE", "PROTOCOL", "ADDRESS"
                                      printf "%-12s %-12s %-12s\n", "---------", "--------", "-------" }
                                   {  printf "%-12s %-12s %-12s\n", $2, $3, $4 }')

printf '    %s\n' '->' "${ip_status[@]}" '->'
```

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html