# Read column from file and run commands with the values

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have such textfile:

```
313 "88.68.245.12"
189 "87.245.108.11"
173 "84.134.230.11"
171 "87.143.88.4"
158 "77.64.132.10"
....
```

I want to `grep` only the IP from the first 10 lines, run `whois` over the IP adress and from that output I want to `grep` the line where it says `netname`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: this is quite basic and has been asked repeatedly here. What did you try?

Comment: Wow I dont think it is basic.. I am trying with awk and grep at the moment.

Comment: `awk -F'"' '{print $2}' file | xargs whois | grep 'netname'`

Comment: Avinash, where is the input textfile in your command?

Comment: piping to whois says "Now whois server is known for this kind of object."

Comment: @SirBenBenji you can use a `while read` loop and keep track of the lines you've read so far.

Comment: You mean like this? `head -n 10 myFile | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | while read -r file; do whois;`

Comment: Give a read to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122441/how-do-i-read-a-variable-on-a-while-loop

Comment: Sorry nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the file with `while - read`:

```
while IFS='"' read -r a ip c
do
    echo "ip: $ip"
    whois "$ip" | grep netname
done < <(head -10 file)
```

This is giving `IFS='"'` so that the field separator is a double quote `"`. This way, the values within double quotes will be stored in `$ip`.

Then, we print the ip and perform the `whois | grep` thing.

Finally, we feed the loop with `head -10 file`, so that we just read the first 10 lines.

Comment: As an aside: I am trying to incorporate a sort feature in your script, but this is not working `done < <(head -10 file | sort)`

Comment: What are you trying to `sort`? The initial file or the output? If it is the output, just pipe everything *after* the whole block I posted.

Comment: TY for following up. Trying to sort the file which has around 1000 of lines then run the whois block on the first ten lines ot that output.

Comment: @SirBenBenji This is quite a different question and, for this, you should indicate desired output, etc. You'd better check some questions with [sort] and [bash] and also `man sort`.

Comment: Follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941781/bash-script-to-sort-input-file-before-piping-to-while-loop#27941781