# Bash script to sort input file before piping to while loop

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have this bash script:

```
while IFS='"' read -r a ip c
do
    echo "ip: $ip"
    whois "$ip" | grep netname
done < <(head -10 file.log)
```

How can I sort the `file.log` file (e.g. with `sort -n -r`) before the first ten lines are taken and handed over to the while-loop?

Comment: `head -10 file.log | sort -nr`

Comment: `sort -nr file.log | head -10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the top 10 lines after sorting, just `sort` it before using `head`:

```
while IFS='"' read -r a ip c
do
    echo "ip: $ip"
    whois "$ip" | grep netname
done < <(sort file.log | head -10)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Apply the `sort` flags you require, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command,

```
sort -nr file.log | head -10
```

Comment: this will sort the top 10 lines, whereas the OP probably wants to get the top 10 sorted lines