# how can I do "git pull" automatically when my server startup

Tags: git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using ec2 instance @ ubuntu . I am trying to automatically do "git pull" after i launched a new instance from my AMI. The repo dir is already in my AMI, all i need is update the repo.

what i am doing now is I put "git pull origin master" in rc.local.... but it doesn't work....

Comment: this might give you a hint: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup

Comment: The title should be changed from server startup to launch a new instance.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work..

sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/blastoff/.git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/blastoff/ fetch origin
sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/blastoff/.git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/blastoff/ merge origin/master

Answer (score 3):

`git --git-dir=some/dir/.git pull origin master` should work

Answer (score 0):

The right place to put the code is not `/etc/rc.local/` but `~/.profile`. You can then run commands as the logged in user without the need for `sudo` or `su` to change the user running the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Taking notes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/659188 and your working answer above, you could apply this to potentially multiple folders by doing something like this in your `rc.local` file (also only pulls current branch instead of always being master):

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# /etc/rc.local

# Ensure folders in array have a trailing slash!

declare -a folders=("/var/www/html/project1/" "/var/www/html/project2/" "/some/other/location/")

# Update to latest in all above folders

for i in "${folders[@]}"
do
        sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=$i/.git --work-tree=$i fetch origin
        sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=$i/.git --work-tree=$i pull
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the `git pull` when the instance has been created (first boot), you could use [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/).

Check the AWS docs [To pass a shell script to an instance with user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

This could be automated by using [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/)/[saltstack](https://docs.saltstack.com) etc but for testing, you could manually upload your script. In step 3 "Configure instance" in the Advance Details, select option As file and put the script below.

[image]

You could upload there your custom script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "git pull or any other custom commands here"
```