# List files starting with two different prefixes - linux

Tags: regex, linux, ls

I have files:

list-a1.jpg, list-a2.jpg

list-b1.jpg, list-b2.jpg

map-a1.jpg,map-a2.jpg

map-b1.jpg, map-b2.jpg

I want to list them using ls. I want to use regex but I have problem with prefixes. How to specify that my filename should start with "list-" or "map-"?
I tried to do:

```
ls [.map-.][.list-.][a-b][1-2].jpg
```

but it is not working as expected.

Comment: you could use grep `ls | grep '^(map|list)-[a-b][1-2].jpg'`

Comment: [List all the files with prefixes from a for loop using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22365552/608639) and friends. Plenty of questions and answer on sister sites, too.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` accepts multiple file parameters: `ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...`:

```
ls list-* map-*
```

For more control, you could take advantage of [bash's curly brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409065/how-does-curly-brace-expansion-work-in-the-shell):

```
ls {list,map}-{a,b}{1,2}.*
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could use *"extended globbing"* - [documentation](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls @(map|list)*
```