# Why is bash only appending first element to array

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to read a list of files from stdin, with each file delimited by a newline, however I'm noticing that only the first element is getting appended to the list. I noticed this by simply entering two strings and then q. Can anyone explain why?

```
files=()
read input

while [ "$input" != "q" ] ; 
do
    files+=( "$input" )
    read input
done

for f  in $files ; 
do
    echo "the list of files is:"
    echo "$f"
    echo "The length of files is ${#files} " #prints 1, even if 2+ are entered
done
```

Comment: In addition to the fine answers below, the number of elements is `${#files[@]}`

Comment: For your future convenience, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points this out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually your `files+=( "$input" )` expression is adding elements to your array but you are not iterating it correctly.

Your last loop should be:

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "element is: $f"
done
```

#### Test (thanks to @fedorqui)

```
$ a+=(1)
$ a+=("hello")
$ a+=(3)
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
1
hello
3
```

Comment: Fast! I added some explanation, feel free to add it to your answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: Thanks I have added most of it to my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that `$files` refers to the head of the array?

Comment: Yes that is true, `$files` gets you first element from array.

Comment: Yes, `$var` is equivalent to `${var[0]}`.

Comment: Why is $var the same as ${var[0]} in this case, but not when I assign a variable to the output of something that gives multiple-line output? I'm able to echo $var in that case and see all of the elements.

Comment: @Bennett: [See this answer for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-array-of-strings-in-bash-script/8880633#8880633)