# how to read an array of strings in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, input, user-input

I am a new `bash` learner. I want to know, how to take a list of string from standard input? After taking all of the strings, I want to print them space separated.

Say the input is like the following:

```
Namibia
Nauru
Nepal
Netherlands
NewZealand
Nicaragua
Niger
Nigeria
NorthKorea
Norway
```

The output should be like:

```
Namibia Nauru Nepal Netherlands NewZealand Nicaragua Niger Nigeria NorthKorea Norway
```

I just can read a variable in `bash` and then can print it like the following:

```
read a
echo "$a"
```

Please, note that :

> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-array-of-strings-in-bash-script) does not answer my question. it is mainly on traversing a declared array. but my case is handling the input and appending the array in runtime as well as detecting the `EOF`

Comment: cat /tmp/file_with_countires | awk '{printf("%s ", $0)}'

Comment: It is not from file, it is from standard input. @klerk

Comment: The [question you referred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-array-of-strings-in-bash-script) is mainly on traversing a declared array. but my case is handling the input and appending the array in runtime as well as detecting the ``EOF`` @Identity1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `read` in a loop with a bash array:

```
countries=()
while read -r country; do
    countries+=( "$country" )
done
echo "${countries[@]}"
```

If used interactively, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> terminates the loop, otherwise it will terminate once `read` fails (e.g. at EOF). Each country is printed on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is a file (you can always save to a file):

```
my_array=( $(<filename) )
echo ${my_array[@]}
```

From standard input:

```
while :
do
read -p "Enter something: " country
my_array+="country"
done
```