# How do I inline an array of strings in a bash for loop?

Tags: bash

How do I inline an array of strings in a bash for loop ? This works:

```
array=(one two)
for i in ${array[*]};do echo $i; done
```

But I'd like to eliminate the extra local variable. I've tried many variations that seem reasonable, for example:

```
for i in ${("one" "two")[*]};do echo $i; done
```

or

```
for i in ${"one" "two"};do echo $i; done
```

In each case, it treats `one` and `two` as commands :(

Comment: Try: `for i in one two; do echo $i; done`

Comment: What's the matter with `for i in "one" "two";do echo $i; done` ?

Comment: You should change `for i in ${array[*]}` to `for i in "${array[@]}"` -- that will protect you from array elements that contain whitespace or globbing characters.

Answer (score 35):

Did you try with:

`for i in "one" "two"; do echo "$i"; done`

Comment: That wouldn't be an array.

Comment: Sorry...I actually deviated from the question because I got the impression from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-array-of-strings-in-bash-script, that this functionality was being sought for (the current question asker commented there). I disregarded an option that one might want to reference another array element (not only the current one) in the body of the loop...should I remove the answer?

Comment: Even if it doesn't answer the question in its strictest interpretation, this answer was useful for me, and is probably for many who arrive here, judging by the upvotes.

Comment: is the implication here that it is simply impossible to inline an array in Bash?

Answer (score 12):

```
for i in {one,two}; do echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work until I realized you that you can't have a space into `{"some text", "test"}`. For anyone else getting stuck, make sure you don't have a space after any commas inside `{...}`