# list files of all components in a workspace using RTC CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, rtc, filelist

I am using RTC CLI to get the list of source files of a single component in a Repository Workspace. My script looks like this:

```
lscm list remotefiles -r local --depth - --workspace "Workspace" "Component" > C:\jazz\Filelist.txt
```

Now I have to list files for all the components in the workspace. I cannot simply remove the "Component" as it is mandatory according to the syntax:

```
lscm list remotefiles [options] <selector> <component> [remotePath]
```

Is there any looping technique in RTC CLI that can be used to get filelist from all the components?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any looping technique in RTC CLI that can be used to get filelist from all the components?

Not exactly: you would need to list all components in your workspace, and then call your command to list files for each component.

See for instance "[RTC Command Line and Listing Components](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/73462/rtc-command-line-and-listing-components)", where you first create a session, and then list within that session:

creating a login session and using that, ie

```
lscm login -r https://csnext.myco.com/ccm6/ -u dlwester@myco.com -n mySession
lscm list components -r mySession
```

[Andrew Niefer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84728/andrew-niefer) suggests:

> It would be better to specify the `-u` option to get UUIDs rather than using component names.

```
lscm -u y list components -r mySession
```

> Also, depending on the scripting language, it may be better to specify `-j` to get json output.

Comment: Hi, I have all the components list. My question is how to call the command for each component? Do I have to give component name every time? I want to run the script during the login. So , providing the component dynamically (interactive way) is not an option for me.

Comment: @ShruthiS It depends on your scripting language. In bash for instance, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8880603/6309. Try and separate the login step from the loop and its `list remotefiles` step.

Comment: It would be better to specify the -u option to get UUIDs rather than using component names.  "lscm -u y list components -r mySession".  Also, depending on the scripting language, it may be better to specify -j to get json output.

Comment: @AndrewNiefer Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.