# How to store NUL output of a program in bash script?

Tags: bash, output, store, nul

Suppose there is a directory '**foo**' which contains several files:

```
ls foo:
1.aa 2.bb 3.aa 4.cc
```

Now in a bash script, I want to count the number of files with specific suffix in '**foo**', and display them, e.g.:

```
SUFF='aa'
FILES=`ls -1 *."$SUFF" foo`
COUNT=`echo $FILES | wc -l`
echo "$COUNT files have suffix $SUFF, they are: $FILES"
```

The problem is: if `SUFF='dd'`, `$COUNT` also equal to `1`. After google, the reason I found is when `SUFF='dd'`, `$FILES` is an empty string, not really the null output of a program, which will be considered to have one line by `wc`.  NUL output can only be passed through pipes. So one solution is:

```
COUNT=`ls -1 *."$SUFF" foo | wc -l`
```

but this will lead to the `ls` command being executed twice. So my question is: is there any more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: the file-names end with `foo`? Can you give one such sample name? Do you want to recursively search in sub-directories also?

Comment: foo is the directory. file-names end with aa,bb,cc. Not need to search sub-directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ FILES=(*)
$ echo "${#FILES[@]}"
4
$ FILES=(*aa)
$ echo "${#FILES[@]}"
2
$ FILES=(*dd)
$ echo "${#FILES[@]}"
0
$ SUFFIX=aa
$ FILES=(*"$SUFFIX")
$ echo "${#FILES[@]}"
2
$ SUFFIX=dd
$ FILES=(*"$SUFFIX")
$ echo "${#FILES[@]}"
0
```

Comment: Wow great explanation!

Comment: @123: That's funny, I didn't write one. Have you visited an ophthalmologist recently?

Comment: Is there a simple way to output contents of FILES one by one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-array-of-strings-in-bash-script

Comment: This is the earliest and best answer till now. So the answer is essentially not using programs like ls or find, but using pathname expansion built in bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the file count, I would actually use `find` for that:

```
find '/path/to/directory' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.aa' -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

This is more reliable as it handles correctly filenames with line breaks. The way this works is that `find` outputs one empty line for each matching file.

**Edit**: If you want to keep the file list in an array, you can use a glob:

```
GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=(*aa)
COUNT=${#arr[@]}
echo "$COUNT"
```

Comment: But I also want to output the names of these files later in the script.

Comment: @Inian What do you mean?

Comment: @Inian It does because they only output a newline for each filename, not the actual filename

Comment: @Inian yes but print0 is only on gnu as well.

Comment: @123: My bad! thought it was a `POSIX` standard, guess only `-print` is portable

Comment: This uses GNU extensions to `find` that simulate the POSIX shell solution `for i in /path/to/directory/*.aa; do [ ! -e "$i" ] && break; echo; done`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
SUFF='aa'
FILES=`ls -1 *."$SUFF" foo`
FILENAMES=`echo $FILES | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`
COUNT=`echo $FILENAMES | wc -w`
echo "$COUNT files have suffix $SUFF, they are: $FILENAMES"
```

if inserted `echo $FILES` in your script,  output is `foo: 1.aa 2.aa 3.aa` so

awk -F ':' '{print $2}' gets `1.aa 2.aa 3.aa` from $FILES variable

`wc -w` prints the word counts

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the option nullglob is unset by default in bash:

> If no matching file names are found, and the shell option nullglob is not enabled, the word is left unchanged. If the nullglob option is set, and no matches are found, the word is removed.

So, just set the nullglob option, and run you code again:

```
shopt -s nullglob
SUFF='aa'
FILES="$(printf '%s\n' foo/*."$SUFF")"
COUNT="$(printf '%.0s\n' foo/*."$SUFF" | wc -l)"
echo "$COUNT files have suffix $SUFF, they are: $FILES"
```

Or better yet:

```
shopt -s nullglob
suff='aa'
files=( foo/*."$suff" )
count=${#file[@]}
echo "$count files have suffix $suff, they are: ${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thx. But if file names contain \n, it may fail.

Comment: @xlwang Ok, solved. The `%.0s\n` prints only a new line per each file.