# Creating an array using folder names using Bash

Tags: bash

How can I create an array consists of folder names?
For example, I have set of folders with names A, B, C, and I want to create the array arr=(A B C).

I tried this:

```
arr=$(ls ~/Desktop/C\ study/seydtb )
```

But after that when I create files using this arr

```
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
    touch ${arr[$i]}.sey
```

I get this:

```
A B C.sey
```

Only the last one has the `.sey` suffix.

Comment: Post some code, dude, or more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array of strings in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `ls`, if you need globbing.

```
a=(~/Desktop/C\ study/seydtb/*)
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
  echo $i
done
```