# How to keep spaces in strings when converting to an array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I am currently working with a bash script. I have a csv file where every line looks like the following:

```
1,ABC DEF
2,GHI JKL
```

I want to create an array with only values in the second field, and then print them.

My current solution is the following:

```
myarr=($(awk -F, '{print $2}' filename.csv))
for i in "${myarr[@]}" 
do
    echo $i
done
```

My output looks like this:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

When I need it to look like this:

```
ABC DEF
GHI JKL
```

I need the result to be in a variable for future operations!

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need them in an array, or do you just need the output you show?

Comment: I actually need them in an array!

Answer (score 3):

```
mapfile -t myarr < <(awk -F, '{print $2}' filename.csv)
declare -p myarr
```

Output:

```
declare -a array='([0]="ABC DEF" [1]="GHI JKL")'
```

---

See: `help mapfile`, `help declare`

Answer (score 3):

If you want values in shell array then don't use `awk`. Just use a loop like this:

```
arr=()
while IFS=, read _ val; do
   arr+=("$val")
done < file

# check array content
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="ABC DEF" [1]="GHI JKL")'

# loop through array
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$i"
   # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. when using `declare` i can see the array looking the way I want it to. But when I iterate over it, using the same for loop I used before, I still get the wrong output ("ABC DEF" is printed in two separate lines).

Comment: See this answer on how to iterate an array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/548225 Make sure you quote it properly as shown in answer.

Comment: I have added sample code for looping though array. Let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply read the entire line into the array, *then* strip the first field.

```
mapfile -t myarr < filename.csv
myarr=("${myarr[@]#*,}")
```