# How to avoid an error when listing nonexistent files?

Tags: bash

I'm grouping files by dates in the filenames and processing them by groups.

```
for m in {01..12}; do
  for d in {01..31}; do
    f=`ls ./mydir/2018.${m}.${d}T*.jpg`
    # process files
  done
done
```

However, the code raises error if no files exist for some dates, e.g.,

> ls: cannot access '2018.01.20T*.jpg': No such file or directory

How can I skip missing dates?

Comment: the error message is sent to stdout (fd #2) so just redirect stdout to `/dev/null`, eg: `ls ./mydir/2018.${m}.${d}T*.jpg 2>/dev/null`; another option would be to test for the existence of the file before trying to `ls` it but this gets a bit messy with that wildcard (*), so the easiest (imo) is to just redirect stdout (fd #2) to `/dev/null`; I'm also assuming that whatever `# process files` entails, it knows how to handle an empty `${f}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `nullglob` so non-matching wildcards expand to nothing. Then you can [skip parsing `ls` altogether](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and simply iterate over the matching files.

```
shopt -s nullglob

for m in {01..12}; do
  for d in {01..31}; do
    for f in ./mydir/2018.${m}.${d}T*.jpg; do
      # process file
    done
  done
done
```

If you want all the file names at once, store them in an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash). Arrays are better than a plain strings because they can handle file names with spaces and other special characters.

```
shopt -s nullglob

for m in {01..12}; do
  for d in {01..31}; do
    files=(./mydir/2018.${m}.${d}T*.jpg)
    # process files
    echo "processing ${files[@]}..."
  done
done
```

---

> What's the cleanest way to localise the shopt so as to restore nullglob to its original (unknown) value after this block?

Use a subshell: surround the block with parentheses. A subshell creates a child process which ensures changes don't leak into the parent.

```
(
    shopt -s nullglob
    ...
)
```

It's polite to do this whenever you're changing shell options, and it's an elegant alternative to `pushd`+`popd`. Note that any variable assignments will be local to the subshell, so be careful there.

Comment: What's the cleanest way to localise the shopt so as to restore nullglob to its former value after this block?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, using find:

Assume the following dir:

```
$ ls -l mydir/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1  0 Jan 23 16:46 2018.01.20Thellowet.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1  0 Jan 23 16:47 2018.04.24Thellowet.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1  0 Jan 23 16:46 some_random_crap
-rw-r--r-- 1  0 Jan 23 16:46 wet
-rw-r--r-- 1  0 Jan 23 16:46 when
-rw-r--r-- 1  0 Jan 23 16:46 who
-rw-r--r-- 1  0 Jan 23 16:46 wtf
```

Using find:

```
find ./mydir/ -type f -regextype sed -regex ".*2018\.[0-9]\{,2\}\.[0-9]\{,2\}T.*\.jpg.*" -exec echo "---{}" \;
```

Gives (minor processing of data by appending `---` to the file name):

```
---./mydir/2018.04.24Thellowet.jpg
---./mydir/2018.01.20Thellowet.jpg
```

NOTE: This will also return files that have `2018.00.xy` or `2018.xy.00` where x and y can be any number between 0 and 9

---

#### Regex explained:

`.*` : any pattern

`[0-9]{,2}`: a 2 digit number

The `\` are used to escape special characters.