# Is there a way to make bash loops work properly when variables with spaces are involved?

Tags: bash, macos, loops, unix, homebrew

and thanks in advance for your help!

I'm having an issue with a piece of code I'm writing to automate the setup of Homebrew on my Mac.
Here's the code I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

brew="
app1 test
app2
app3
"

for i in $brew; do
    echo brew install $i
done
```

My expected output is this:

```
brew install app1 test
brew install app2
brew install app3
```

But, the actual output of the script is this:

```
brew install app1
brew install test
brew install app2
brew install app3
```

I've tried quoting both the "i" and "$brew" commands in my loop with no results. If anyone has any potential solutions, please share them! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array.

If you need array elements which include spaces, quote these elements:

```
brew=("app1 test" app2 app3)
```

When looping over the array elements, also use quotes to preserve spaces in them:

```
for i in "${brew[@]}"; do
    echo brew install $i
done
```

See also: [Loop through an array of strings in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/111036)