# Why linux shell script array cannot iterate directly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

There are some files in my work directory like below:

```
20191101.data.lz4
20191104.data.lz4
20191105.data.lz4
20191106.data.lz4
20191107.data.lz4
20191108.data.lz4
20191111.data.lz4
20191112.data.lz4
20191113.data.lz4
20191114.data.lz4
20191115.data.lz4
20191118.data.lz4
20191119.data.lz4
```

Now I need to process these files. If I use below command defin a array the `for` loop work as my expect, print all file in my work directory.

```sh
FILE_LIST=$(ls /my/work/dir)
for EACH_FILE in ${FILE_LIST}
do
    echo $EACH_FILE
done
```

But if I defin array as below,  the `for` loop only print the first element of array.

```sh
FILE_LIST=(20191101.data.lz4
20191104.data.lz4
20191105.data.lz4
20191106.data.lz4
20191107.data.lz4
20191108.data.lz4
20191111.data.lz4
20191112.data.lz4
20191113.data.lz4
20191114.data.lz4
20191115.data.lz4
20191118.data.lz4
20191119.data.lz4)
for EACH_FILE in ${FILE_LIST}
do
    echo $EACH_FILE
done
```

But I found I can iterate every element of second array in below way:

```sh
for EACH_FILE in ${FILE_LIST[*]}
do
    echo $EACH_FILE
done
```

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8880603/11122351) most answer explained how to use `for` loop in seconds way, but it didn't explain why my first way not working. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21178462/11122351)'s situation B, my first way should works fine, but it didn't.
I am still pretty confuse why the second arraya can't iterate by the first way?
Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Because that's how array variables work in bash?

Comment: Reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays might be helpful, or the relevant parts of the official bash manual.

Comment: Running your scripts through https://shellcheck.net is also a good way of finding problems (You have quite a few).

Comment: @fajinyu : In your first case, `FILE_LIST` is not an array. In the second case, it is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I relized my problem, but I still wonder what `FILE_LIST` type is. A string?

Comment: use `typeset -p <variable_name>` to see the contents of a variable; in your first case `typeset -p FILE_LIST` will show you a single string consisting of your filenames; in the 2nd case you'll see you've populated an array with the list of filenames

Answer (score 0):

Small changes you need to take care of..

```
FILE_LIST+=(20191101.data.lz4
20191104.data.lz4
20191105.data.lz4
20191106.data.lz4
20191107.data.lz4
20191108.data.lz4
20191111.data.lz4
20191112.data.lz4
20191113.data.lz4
20191114.data.lz4
20191115.data.lz4
20191118.data.lz4
20191119.data.lz4)
for EACH_FILE in ${FILE_LIST[@]}
do
   echo $EACH_FILE
done
```

[image]