# Bash check string that don't match on order

Tags: bash

how to compare string in bash? I only want to compare words, not word order
for example i have variable

```
VAR1=eu-endpoint-2021.09.20 prod-store-2021.09.20 service-trace-2021.09.20
```

and another variable that stores the same info but with different order

```
VAR2=prod-store-2021.09.20 eu-endpoint-2021.09.20 service-trace-2021.09.20
```

and how can i compare this only by words? nor the words order
for example

```
if $VAR1 == $VAR2 
then
do smth;
else
do smth;
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just sort them then compare the result, e.g.:

```
$ VAR1='eu-endpoint-2021.09.20 prod-store-2021.09.20 service-trace-2021.09.20'
$ VAR2='prod-store-2021.09.20 eu-endpoint-2021.09.20 service-trace-2021.09.20'
```

```
$ if [[ $(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$VAR1" | sort) = $(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$VAR2" | sort) ]]; then echo same; else echo diff; fi
same
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both your input string only contains parts that don't contain any spaces, we can

- Convert the strings into arrays `($VAR1)`
- Loop over array1: [Loop through an array of strings in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash)
- Check if current element exist in array2: [Check if a Bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value)

  - If not, set result to `false`, and `break` out of the loop

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash

VAR1='eu-endpoint-2021.09.20 prod-store-2021.09.20 service-trace-2021.09.20'
VAR2='prod-store-2021.09.20 eu-endpoint-2021.09.20 service-trace-2021.09.20'

ARR1=($VAR1)
ARR2=($VAR2)

RES=1

for i in "${ARR1[@]}"; do
    [[ ! " ${ARR2[*]} " =~ " ${i} " ]] && RES=0 && break
done

[ $RES -eq 1 ] && echo 'Equal' || echo 'Not equal'
```

---

- Will show `Equal` for the provided example strings as you [can try here](https://tio.run/##dY4/b8IwEMX3@xSPNMKlkiHxVqFIZWDtkEpdrAz5cwiryAYndCn0q6d22oGh3PR@7@7eXVP3@3F8mK0aY1dNAKL3TZkXgs@SbXd0xg5SZSpfZs9LleHoXSf7wXm@dXv2n6ZlOfi6vW2IGKYK8f/WnRP3w2hThtce0/jhIoL6BbUgKrdvRU60cx4GxiJJv@K0fqmuyRqdI4TSGjMkmFpKP1XXAMX35JioqwrzOWJUFkXjuf6gzlkm0kiDD8kn5JjGuN07iO3pXB8ELpc/fnUDePLG8Qc).
- If you change any of the strings, you'll get `Not equal` as you [can try here](https://tio.run/##dY4xb8IwEIX3@xWPNMKlkiHxVqFIZWDtkEpdrAxOcgiryAYndCn0r6dx2oGh3PS@d3fvrjbdfhgeZqvaulU9AtH7pswLYfgs2bVHb10vVabyZfa8VBmOwbey633gW7fj8Gkbln0wzW1DxDRViP@37py4H0abcvztMY0vLiKoX1ALonL7VuREOx9gYR2S9CtO65fqmqzResJYWmOGBFNL6afqOkLxPTk26qrCfI4YlUVRBzYf1HrHRBrp6EPyCTmmMW72HmJ7OpuDwOXyx6@@B0/eMPwA).