# How to iterate through array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have written some script in bash but it won't work. Can anybody help me with this.
I am providing the script here:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array=("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")

for (( i=0; i<${array[@]}; i++));
do
        echo "items: $i"
done
```

I want to iterate through the array.
Coz when ever I do it I'm getting an error saying:: arr1.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Use `${#array[@]}` inside the `(( ))`

Comment: Sure you're using bash to execute your script and not sh?

Comment: Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash#comment110320649_8880633) about `"`'s around the array syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat iterate_array.sh 
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array=("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")
for  i in ${!array[@]}; do
        echo ${array[$i]}
done
$ ./iterate_array.sh 
red
blue
green
yellow
```

Is that what you want?