# How to split variable value and iterate the step in GitHub Action

Tags: bash, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to pass variable `poetry-config` with multiple values:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Install poetry (with github.com token)
      uses: ./actions/setup-poetry
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
        poetry-version: "1.4.2"
        poetry-project: .
        poetry-install-arguments: "--only main --no-root"
        poetry-config: |
          "http-basic.abc1 test1 value1"
          "http-basic.abc2 test2 value2"
```

In `action.yml`, I need to run the command:

```
poetry config http-basic.abc1 test1 value1
poetry config http-basic.abc2 test2 value2
```

My current `action.yml` is:

```yaml
name: Setup Poetry
description: Set up python and poetry

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: poetry config
      shell: bash
      run: poetry config ${{ inputs.poetry-config }}
      working-directory: ${{ inputs.poetry-project }}
```

How can I split the `poetry-config` and iterate step on it?

Comment: Simply use a loop in Bash to iterate through the list.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash.

Comment: Example: `run: for CONF in ${{ inputs.poetry-config }}; do poetry config "$CONF"; done`

Comment: As each line of `poetry-config` may contain spaces, you might have to need quotes around  `${{ ... }}`. You need to test this on your side and make adjustments accordingly.

Comment: I need to do this is Github workflow actions.yml only .

Comment: `run` section runs a Bash script. That's where you can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

you want to run these two commands:

```
poetry config http-basic.abc1 test1 value1
poetry config http-basic.abc2 test2 value2
```

of which only the beginning part is fixed and the rest is configuration data:

```
poetry config

          http-basic.abc1 test1 value1
          http-basic.abc2 test2 value2
```

so you have two records with three fields each:

```
          http-basic.abc1 test1 value1
          http-basic.abc2 test2 value2
```

as you already learned, you can provide this as input to your action, just don't quote the records:

```yaml
        poetry-config: |
          http-basic.abc1 test1 value1
          http-basic.abc2 test2 value2
```

and then when you "run" the input, make it a [pipeline¹](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) with [`xargs(1)`²](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/findutils/xargs.1.en.html) on the right hand side executing each records fields as arguments of the `poetry config` command:

```yaml
      run: echo '${{ inputs.poetry-config }}' | xargs -L1 poetry config
```

This will then run one invocation of `poetry config` per *line*  in the input.

If the line is empty, it won't run for that line.

If there is no line or a single empty line, it would run `poetry config` once (without any other arguments), unless you add the `-r` switch:

```yaml
      run: echo '${{ inputs.poetry-config }}' | xargs -rL1 poetry config
```

this then supports no input and up to *n* lines.

finally (simplified):

```yaml
jobs:
  job:
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    steps:
    - uses: ./actions/setup
      with:
        config: |
          http-basic.abc1 test1 value1
          http-basic.abc2 test2 value2
```

`./actions/setup/action.yml`

```
name: setup action

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - shell: bash
      run: |
        echo '${{ inputs.config }}' | 
          xargs -rL1 poetry config
```

---

¹ 2.9.2 Pipelines
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02

² `xargs(1)` https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/findutils/xargs.1.en.html